# How to change NSCursor globally?

Tags: macos, nstextview, nscursor

I am developing an application with several windows and views (`NSTextView`, etc.).

I would like to change the cursor globally in my application, so that even if the cursor enters the `trackingRect` of (for instance) an `NSTextView` it does not change.

Is this possible?

---

PS: I need also to revert back to the usual behaviour.

Comment: If you're asking for a switch you can turn off and on to make a specific cursor show up on any view, that does not exist. You have to subclass each view and override the appropriate methods.

Comment: Ah... how could I disable the change of cursor for a set of views? (NSTextView, PDFView, etc.) Is it do you think achievable without subclassing?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible. I had an almost similar requirement, and here is how I solved it:

When creating a window, create a transparent view with the same `frame` as that of the window. Then add a cursor rect to the view (that extends to the latter's `bounds`) for your specific cursor. Finally add it as the last subview of the window's `contentView`, so that it acts as an overlay. When this overlay is present, cursor rects of underlying views are not activated.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43886799/7908996 for detailed instructions and working code (read *the window's `contentView`* instead of *`WebView`*). It also describes how to revert back to the usual behaviour.

Hope that helps! :)